# Contraseña alfanumerica con getch()

Tags: c++, c

Estoy programando un sistema de login, las contraseñas son alfanumericas. Por ahora estoy armando la lectura de la contraseña con getch y al momento de que registra una tecla valida imprime en pantalla un '*'. 
El problema es que no puedo hacer que lea tambien los numeros que contiene la contraseña.

```
void encriptaPass(char pass[])
{
int i=0;
char num[1];
int valor;
while(pass[i]!=13)
{
    pass[i]=getch();
    if(pass[i]>32 && i<20)
    {
        ///if (pass[i] >= '0' && pass[i] <= '9')
        // {
        //     valor = valor * 10 + pass[i] - '0';
        //      sprintf(num, "%d", valor);
        //     strcat(pass,num);
        // }
        putchar('*');
        i++;
    }
    else if(pass[i]==8 && i>0)
    {
        putchar(8);
        putchar(' ');
        putchar(8);
        i--;
    }
}
pass[i]='\0';
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si te has fijado, pero en esta variable:

```
char num[1];
```

Solo te entra **un caracter**.

Al llamar a `sprintf(num, "%d", valor);` estás almacenando en `num` **una cadena de caracteres**... y en C las cadenas de caracteres finalizan con el caracter nulo `'\0'`, luego lo deseable es que `num` tenga, como mínimo, espacio para dos caracteres.

```
char num[20]; // Espacio para numeros de hasta 19 dígitos
```

Luego, si seguimos leyendo el código comentado, nos encontramos con

```
strcat(pass,num);
```

Y aquí tenemos otro problema... `pass` **no tiene finalizador de cadena**, luego el programa empezará a recorrer la memoria hasta encontrar con uno y, en ese punto, añadirá el contenido de `num`... No puedes llamar a `strcat` con cadenas que no están debidamente finalizadas.

```
pass[i+1] = 0;
strcat(pass, num);
```

Claro que esto te lo puedes ahorrar y decirle a `sprintf` que te escriba directamente a partir de `pass[i+1]`:

```
i += sprintf(pass + i + 1, "%d", valor);
```

Eso sí, no hay que olvidarse de incrementar `i`... en caso contrario vas a reemplazar todo lo que escribas en `pass`.

Aun así me da que esta no es exactamente la lógica que quieres que tenga tu ofuscador de contraseñas... pero como no detallas el algoritmo a implementar es complicado darte una respuesta más acertada

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas prueba con esto:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 int main()
 {
   char s[10] = { 0 };
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
    s[i] = _getch(); _putch('*');
    if (s[i] == 13) break;
 };
 printf("\nYour pass is %s", s);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considera por favor editar y aportar una explicación a tu código, de manera que sea fácil de entender para todos y todas